# Using next day in strtotime with PHP

Tags: php

It's monday and I run the following:

```
$d = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('this tuesday'));
```

Which gives me date the of tomorrow, 08-07-2014

If i run

```
$d = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('next tuesday'));
```

It provides me the same.

But how can i easiest get the next tuesday in the next week (not tomorrow)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with:

```
strtotime('this tuesday +1 week')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
$d = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('next week tuesday'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add days also to get desire result like :

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this tuesday +7 days'));
```